# How to export all the link in a csv or text file?

Tags: python, api, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import urllib.request as req
import re
import bs4
import csv


url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_China_Morning_Post"
request=req.Request(url,headers={
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36)"})
with req.urlopen(request) as response:
    data=response.read().decode("utf-8")

root=bs4.BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
links_list=root.find_all('a')
print(type(links_list))
for link in links_list:
        if 'href' in link.attrs:
            text=str(link.attrs['href'])
            with open('link.csv','a',newline='',encoding='utf_8_sig') as csvfile:
                    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                    writer.writerow(text)
            #print(str(link.attrs['href']))   #for debug


# matchno=root.find_all(class_="nav-link",href=True)
# print(matchno)
```

As I run above code, I got the below output in Excel file:

```
/,w,i,k,i,/,S,C,M,P,_,(,d,i,s,a,m,b,i,g,u,a,t,i,o,n,)
/,w,i,k,i,/,F,i,l,e,:,S,C,M,P,_,l,o,g,o,.,s,v,g
```

[image]

May I know how to turn all those link to correct one like this?

```
/wiki/SCMP_(disambiguation)
/wiki/File:SCMP_logo.svg
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
You've included a *lot* of overhead in this post.  Your problem is that you should never have broken the original URL string into individual characters.  Trace your code, learn where you did that, and ... *stop doing that*.

Comment: It seems to be this is a complete MCVE. I could repro the problem easily.

Comment: Hi @Prune, the post seems to be a MRE. Although `print(str(link.attrs['href']))` displays the correct output, the problem `/,w,i,k,i,/,F,i,l,e,:,S,C,M,P,_,l,o,g,o,.,s,v,g` is reproduced in the Excel file `link.csv`. You should remove your downvote

Comment: @BlackRaven: thanks for back-checking me.  I can't check for myself at the moment, but I trust your evidence.  I've removed my closure vote.  I can't remove the downvote until there's an edit, and I made the mistake of reviewing the outstanding edit, rather than making a trivial improvement to force it through.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to write the links to the file:

```py
with open('link.csv','w', encoding='utf_8_sig') as csvfile:
    for link in links_list:
        if 'href' in link.attrs:
            csvfile.write(f"{link['href']}\n")
```

The [`writer.writerow(text)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) accepts the `row` argument that is a list of values (column values) to write to file. Since you pass strings, they are parsed as list of separate chars, hence, the commas between each char.

Answer (score 0):

Need to move to next line with `\n` after writing each line

```
root=bs4.BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
links_list=root.find_all('a')
print(type(links_list))
for link in links_list:
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        with open('link.csv','a',newline='',encoding='utf_8_sig') as csvfile:
            csvfile.write(str(link.attrs['href'])+'\n')
```

Output Excel `link.csv`

[image]